# Where can I find ITestDiscoverer? (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: visual-studio-sdk

I'm trying to write a new test add in for Visual Studio 2015 and having a really hard time working out what the "current" way to do it is. Everything I google seems to be for older versions.

I installed the Visual Studio Extension Components and I've tried a bunch of NuGet packages but can't find the one I'm seemingly looking for.

Is there a specific NuGet package I should use?

Also, any other info on how to test/debug the adapter?

Comment: FYI it's "NuGet", pronounced "new get", not "nugget".

Comment: Lol, I'm going to blame that on the spell correct in edge.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late for flukus, but for all the googlers out there:

The API hasn't changed much between VS2012 and VS2015 (just a few extensions, e.g. support for traits), so all the blog entries out there still are valid.

You can find the relevant assemblies in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow` (and the similar location for `11.0` and `12.0`).

Debugging: Make sure you have the following settings in you VSIX project:

- Debug

  - Start external program: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`
  - Command line arguments: `/rootsuffix Exp`
- VSIX

  - Create VSIX
  - Deploy VSIX
- Set the VSIX project as Startup Project

When you hit F5 it will install and launch your extension in another Visual Studio instance. Your test runner will run in the processes `devenv.exe`, `te.processhost.managed.exe`, `vstest.discoveryengine.exe`, and `vstest.executionengine.exe`. You need to attach your debugger to these processes in order to set breakpoints. This can be tricky as some of these processes spawn and immediately execute your code. Best thing is to call [Debugger.Launch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx) from your test runner.

Comment: Just to this, make sure in your vsixmanifest you have added the project as a "UnitTestExtension" (not in the list of Asset types you need to type manually), "Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" and "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Assembly" (you might not need the assembly one but it can't hurt!